# What is the Best Method to Upload My Photos Library to Amazon Cloud Drive Using the Amazon Desktop App?

Tags: mac, photos, amazon-cloud-drive

I recently purchased the unlimited option for Amazon Cloud Drive and would like to have an off site copy of my Photos library from my Mac. I was wondering if anyone might have any suggestions of the best way to upload a Photos library from a Mac to Amazon Cloud Drive, whether that be uploading the library itself or exporting each folder and the exporting it. It seems the second option would take quite a while for larger libraries. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Amazon-Cloud-Drive-Desktop-PC/dp/B00P31G9PQ

Comment: I have the desktop app already. But was more so looking for the best way to actually uploading the pics from the library using the app

Comment: Please edit your question and Title to include that info.

Comment: "What is the Best Method to Upload My Photos using Amazons desktop app" would be a good title.

Comment: @DanielFuller - ExpanDrive can do what you want.